# Creating a table with for loop over a list

Tags: tables, loops

I am currently trying to learn Latex with writing my CV with it. I am stuck at the point that I want to list my skills. 
I just want to have a simple function that takes a dynamic list of skills and creates a table out of it. I've read a lot of stuff using pggfor or etoolbox and more and I am kinda exhausted. Most of them are not easy to read and seem too complicated for a beginner.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\createskill[2]{%
    \textsc{\textbf{#1}} & #2
}

\newcommand\createskills[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{r|l}
    \makeatletter
    \@for\thisitem:=#1\do{\thisitem \\} %in the last iteration of loop a new line is added also 
    \makeatother
  \end{tabular}
}

% usage
\newcommand{\skillone}{\createskill{programming}{Python Java }}
\newcommand{\skilltwo}{\createskill{math}{Calculus Statistics}}
\createskills{\skillone, \skilltwo}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that because of `\\` in the last iteration a new line is also added and I get a empty table row with only a sperator. I am open to suggestions to have a for loop that won't add this `\\` in the last iteration.

[image: the end result]

I tried another solution with using `\foreach` command. Even though I got rid of the unnecessary `\\` in the last row, this doesn't work well when contained within `tabular` environment.

```
\newcommand\createtablecontent[1]{%
    \foreach \x [count=\xi] in {#1} {\ifthenelse{\xi=1}{\x}{\\ \x}}
}

\newcommand\createskillsanothertry[1]{% called in the same way \createskills
    \begin{tabular}{r|l} 
      \createtablecontent{#1}
      \end{tabular}
}
```

[image]

with the above solution I only have the first row, and 22 warnings which seem quite complex.

If I exclude the tabular environment I have the desired behaviour of creating 2 lines of content.

```
\newcommand\createskillsanothertry[1]{%
      \createtablecontent{#1}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, show a minimal document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your code does not compile. I've suggested a solution to making dynamical tables, but I would be nicer to know if you're using packages or specific settings in order to avoid clashes.

Comment: @JairoADelRio I am trying to find the cause but couldn't find it. I picked the related commands to the problem from .cls file and the .tex file but it seems like it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `expl3`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\createskills}{m}
 {
  \begin{tabular}{r|l}
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \irestmycase_skill:n
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \irestmycase_skill:n
 {
  \tl_if_single:nTF { #1 }
   {
    \exp_last_unbraced:No \__irestmycase_skill_process:nn #1
   }
   {
    \__irestmycase_skill_process:nn #1
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__irestmycase_skill_process:nn
 {
  \textsc{#1} & #2 \\
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% usage
\newcommand{\skillone}{{programming}{Python Java}}
\newcommand{\skilltwo}{{math}{Calculus Statistics}}
\createskills{\skillone, \skilltwo}

\bigskip

\createskills{
  {programming}{Python Java},
  {math}{Calculus Statistics}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We need not `\directlua` nor `expl3` to solve this problem. The following solution is based only on TeX primitives:

```
\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\skilllist{}
\def\createskill#1#2{\addto\skilllist{#1&#2\cr}}
\def\printskills{\vbox{\halign{\hfil\bf##\ \vrule\strut&\ ##\hfil\cr\skilllist}}}

\createskill{programming}{java python lua TeX}
\createskill{mathematics}{calculus statistics}
\createskill{languages}{english spanish korean}

\printskills
```

The `\createskill` macro adds the data to the internal `\skillist` in the form usable in `\halign` (table) parameter. And `\printskills` prints the table using `\halign` primitive and using the data from `\skillist`.

Answer (score 0):

Using LuaLaTeX, in case this option is available, that's pretty easy. You only need two functions, `\createskill` and `\printskill` (you can rename them *ad libitum*). I've used TeX Gyre Schola only for displaying because it supports small caps.

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
%LuaLaTeX is mandatory here
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
Skills = Skills or {}

function capitalise(str)
    local gmatch = unicode.utf8.gmatch
    local upper = unicode.utf8.upper
    local sub = unicode.utf8.sub
    local uppers = {}
    for w in str:gmatch("%S+") do
        table.insert(uppers, upper(sub(w,1,1))..sub(w,2))
    end
    return table.concat(uppers, " ")
end

function createskill(a,b)
    local str = [[\textbf{\textsc{]]..a..[[}} & ]]..capitalise(b)
    table.insert(Skills, str)
end

function printskills()
    tex.print([[\begin{tabular}{r|l}]])
    tex.print(table.concat(Skills, [[\\]]))
    tex.print([[\end{tabular}]])
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\createskill}[2]{\directlua{createskill("#1", "#2")}}
\newcommand{\printskills}{\directlua{printskills()}}
\begin{document}
%You add skills with this macro
\createskill{programming}{java python lua}
\createskill{mathematics}{calculus statistics}
\createskill{languages}{english spanish korean}
%And you print them all with this macro:
\printskills
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with LuaLatex but i might give it a try if this is the only way and we can not find another solution which is simpler.